# How to use regular expression to extract string separated by spaces?

Tags: regex

My sample string is
"Used 1908 Honda 123 Test Coupe"

I want to extract substrings ("Used", "1908", "Honda", "123", "Test" and "Coupe") from the above string using regex. How to use the regex for same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex isn't always the answer. Depending on the programming language you use, you'd be better off splitting your string.

Say you have python, you can do something as simple as:

```py
text = "Used 1908 Honda 123 Test Coupe"
parts = text.split(" ")
```

However, if you absolutely must, here's the simplest regex for your purpose:

```regex
\w+
```

It simply matches anything that's a word character (whish is a-z, A-Z, and 0-9) and is repeated once or more. It neatly excludes all whitespaces.

Comment: I am using web scraper (chrome extension) and trying to extract field values. there I need to enter regex to get substrings from the string. I tried \w+ and was able to get the first word ("Used). For second word, I used regex \s+\w+ and got ("1908"). Can you help me get third, fourth and fifth words ? I am trying to find ways of ignoring first 2 spaces and fetching third word but it is not working.